# In xcode14 + ios16, the uiview is not visible above the keyboard

Tags: ios16, xcode14

I am developing a chat app. I tested the app on xcode14, ios16. If you click the emoticon button while the keyboard is exposed to write a chat text, the uiview should be exposed on the virtual keyboard, but it is not visible. In xcode13 it works fine. Is there any way?

//not work!!!!

`self.emoticonView!.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)  let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count  UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(self.emoticonView!)`